# Want partial upload of large file. HTML / PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to have php script that uploads partial files.  Like the first 1 MB of a very large file.   Can this be done in PHP with a regular form upload?  Like, it close off the connection after 1mb upload... 
I've looked a lot of uploaders (html5/javascript/flash), and it seems some support 'chunking', and file size limits which sounds 1/2 of what I want.. but I'd of course somehow need to know that it's only a partial of a full file.

Comment: What good is part of a file - broken up arbitrarily at 1MB?

Comment: part of a cake, is better than no cake at all!

Comment: Analogies aside - what can you do with 1mb of an 8mb file? Absolutely nothing. You might as well write a PHP script to generate a bunch of 1MB garbage files for you.

Comment: Well, there are so many reasons you only need a partial file.  For text log files, you can certainly analysis just the start of it.  Many video formats, seeing the intro of it is enough.   I don't need the whole file.  Anyway, I'm talking the first 1mb or 10mb of a 2gb file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using javascript you can read the file into a blob on the client (which is far quicker than uploading), cut out everything after the first 1mb, and send it to php via ajax. It wouldn't technically be a traditional php upload form, but it would seem like one to the user.

Comment: He wants the file to get uploaded up to 1MB. He doesn't care how big it actually is. He just wants the first 1MB of every file. Weird, I know.

Comment: I have tried unsucessfully to read in large files via javascript.  Seems to crash with a 800mb file.   This page for example, under monitoring the progress of a read  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: I don't know if you have a bad computer or bad browser, but that link read a 12mb file in 1 or 2 seconds without crashing.

Comment: I've got 6GB or ram, and the html5 page can't read an 800mb file.  Like I said, I want partial uploads of very large files.  I could upload a 12mb file no problem.   Regular HTML forms will start the upload of a 800MB file, no problem... I'm wondering from the php side can I monitor during upload, then stop the upload out after 1mb, while still providing a post upload page.   A JS solution could work too, but I'm not sure it can read in a very large file like that.